# Unable to configure JPA properties in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

I have a Java project with JPA and it seems to work fine with reading/writing to the database.

I need to generate metamodel classes from the Properties window -> JPA (Discover annotated classes automatically), but the whole JPA window is greyed out and I'm unable to select anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, secondary click on the project, project facets, select JPA (the version you want) and below it should appear in yellow "Further configuration available ....".
You must select Generic 2.1 for example, if it did not appear, you would have to install Dali JPA Tools from the eclipse marketplace

Comment: Dali JPA Tools were already installed but there was an error when I tried to update. So, I installed a new version of eclipse and it's working fine now. Thanks.